# Jmeter - JSON Extractor

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I'm trying create a json expression path that returns the id when the reference with `{" id ":" 00000000000000000000000004640254 "}`. I have tried with

```
$.[?(@.Relationship[?(@.Ref.id=='00000000000000000000000004640254')])].id
```

but it doesn't return data

Json message is

```
[
    {
        "id": "234567890234567890",
        "Relationship": [
            {
                "type": "Indirect",
                "Ref": {"id": "00000000000000000000000004640253_01"}
            },
            {
                "type": "Direct",
                "Ref": {"id": "00000000000000000000000004640254"}
            }
        ],
        "Specification": {"id": "Gold123AS"}
    },
    {
        "id": "234567890234567891",
        "Relationship": [
            {
                "type": "Indirect",
                "Ref": {"id": "00000000000000000000000004640253_02"}
            },
            {
                "type": "Direct",
                "Ref": {"id": "00000000000000000000000004640253"}
            }
        ],
        "Specification": {"id": "Gold123AS"}
    }
]
```

if someone can help me, thanks

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with jsonpath; I'll be happy to be proven wrong... One way to handle it is convert to xml.

Comment: Please elaborate what data you are looking for from the JSON.
`$..[?(@.id=='234567890234567891')]` - This will give you the elements against the ID passed.

`$..[?(@.id=='234567890234567891')]..['type']`- This will give you the type related to the id passed.

`$..[?(@.id=='234567890234567891')]..['id']` - This will give you all the ID present for the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this using JSON Extractor as returning the parent node is [not implemented by underlying JsonPath library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/287)

Go for [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language instead, the relevant code would be something like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

0.upto(json.size() -1 , { idx ->
    if (json.get(idx).Relationship.find { it.Ref.id.equals('00000000000000000000000004640254') } != null) {
        vars.put('id', json.get(idx).id as String)
        return
    }
})
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)